# Type of 'json' response is boolean in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, php-curl

I am using the following:

```
<?php
$url = '...';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($response, true);
echo gettype($response); /$response/ THIS RETURNS INTEGER FOR SOME REASON!
?>
```

So the `$response` I am getting is of type integer, and I am unable to read the elements of this JSON.

Also note that when I echo the response, 1 is printed after it.

Comment: can you print_r($response) and add it to your questions?

Comment: "THIS RETURNS INTEGER FOR SOME REASON!" — Presumably, because the JSON consists of an integer. What did you expect it to be? How about providing a [mcve] (which would need example input to be complete)

Comment: I would like to repeat that I did not downvote your question

Comment: @TobiasGassmann okay, thanks. I dont understand what is provoking the downvoting. Is my question this inappropriate? Anyways, Yoshi seems to have helped me so thank you all.

Comment: as Quentin wrote, include a MCVE in your question. without it the question is incomplete and subject of downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manual for the possible [return values](http://php.net/manual/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-returnvalues). You need to at least use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`.

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
>   success, FALSE on failure.

```
<?php
$url = '...';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true  // <<<< add this
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($response, true);

if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    var_dump(json_last_error_msg());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

'$result' is not defined in your code, double check it?
Perhaps the line "$response = json_decode($response, true);" needs to be changed.
A default value for undefined variable is NULL/False

Comment: I edited my question. This isn't the issue, I am getting the type of $response not $result.

Comment: The function curl_exec returns a true/false value, that is what is stored within $response. Is that what you wanted to check? 

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php